spring-boot: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile
I am just running through the basic spring-boot tutorial Developing Your First Spring Boot Application using Maven and getting stuck at "Running the Example" using mvn spring-boot:run.  Here is the error(s):
mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.example:myproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:3.3.3:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ myproject >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\dev\spring\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\dev\spring\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Recompiling the module because of changed source code.
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [debug parameters release 17] to target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[3,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RestController
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[4,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[8,4] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestMapping
  location: class myproject.MyApplication
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[16,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class myproject.MyApplication
[INFO] 4 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.767 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-12T14:02:34+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[3,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class RestController
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[4,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class SpringBootApplication
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[8,4] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RequestMapping
[ERROR]   location: class myproject.MyApplication
[ERROR] /F:/dev/spring/src/main/java/myproject/MyApplication.java:[16,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable SpringApplication
[ERROR]   location: class myproject.MyApplication
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException


Surprisingly I am unable to find any resolutions to the "cannot find symbol" wrt spring-boot.  I am new to this but assume it's the magic inside spring-boot that provides these dependencies.
My dependencies seem ok:
mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.example:myproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency:3.6.1:tree (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] com.example:myproject:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.5.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.5.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.16:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.16:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.28:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.28:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.28:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.13.3:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.12:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.110 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-12T13:57:42+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


And Java and Maven seem to be installed properly:
> java -version
java version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207, mixed mode, sharing)

> javac -version
javac 17.0.11

> mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: f:\maven
Java version: 17.0.11, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.11
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

> echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.11

and finally my simple code, cut and pasted from the tutorial:
package myproject;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication
{

  @RequestMapping("/")
  String home()
  {
    return "Hello World!";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }

}


You have no imports. You need something like import org.springframework.web.annotation.RequestMapping and a bunch more. Use an IDE which will help you with this.

This question is similar to: What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for that.  I guess I assumed the tutorial would be a "complete" tutorial in using spring-boot.  I am quite familiar with java and importing referenced libraries.  Maybe the author of the spring-boot quick start guide should post a more complete example.  I am using Eclipse but it does not seem to understand spring-boot applications either at is has no suggestions for importing missing classes, unlike it does perfectly with java applications.  For example, I don't even know where those libraries are to be honest as Maven was responsible for getting everything "local".

Maybe this is just a question of where does Maven hide it's imports so I can add that to my classpath and import some classes as suggested by m-deinum

OK, I found all the jars, put them in the build path and did the requisite imports.  Java 101...
